# Get same buttons with different name as list in ionic3 using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angular, button, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic3

I'm new to ionic 3 and I try to get button list using ng-repeate.These buttons differ from name only.
This is my html code

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div ng-repeat="tip in healthTipsButtonList">
        <button ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet()" class="button button-dark clearButton" [color]="'secondary'">{{tip}}</button>
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

and this is typescript code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-read',
  templateUrl: 'read.html',
})
export class ReadPage {
  healthTipsButtonList;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController) {
  this.healthTipsButtonList = ["BEAUTY","FAMILY HEALTH","FITNESS TIPS","HEALTHY TIPS","PREGNANCY"];
}

presentActionSheet() {
  //some thing
}
```

But I got this type of output without any errors.

[image]

This is my ionic environment details

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:
Node : v8.9.4
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 8.1
Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` belongs to angularjs, you should use `*ngFor`

Comment: Is this Angular or AngularJS? `ng-repeat` is AngularJS.

Comment: @DeborahK This is angular.Here is details  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-repeat` belongs to AngularJs, you have to use `*ngFor`

Change following code

```
<div ng-repeat="tip in healthTipsButtonList">
    <button ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet()" class="button button-dark clearButton" [color]="'secondary'">{{tip}}</button>
</div>
```

to

```
<div *ngFor="let tip of healthTipsButtonList">
    <button ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet()" class="button button-dark clearButton" [color]="'secondary'">{{tip}}</button>
</div>
```